# Indy 10: Undeclared Identifier 'TIdBytes'

Tags: delphi, telnet, indy, indy10, delphi-xe4

Sorry if my question is silly!

I'm using **Delphi XE4** and now I'm working on `IdTelnet`. But I got a problem with `OnDataAvailable` event. Take a look at this picture:

[image]

So I cannot work with `OnDataAvailable` Event.

Is this because of Delphi XE4? And How can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [`TIdBytes`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/TIdBytes.html) type is declared in the [`IdGlobal`](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/IdGlobal_pas.html) unit. Add that unit to your uses clause.

Comment: OT: If you were having Total Commander file manager, you might look for type definitions in *.pas files of your Delphi source directory by searching the RegEx pattern like `TIdBytes(\s*)=`, which searches `TIdBytes` followed by any count of word separator (like space and tab) and `=` symbol (it doesn't count with line breaks between type name and `=` symbol, but it's enough to find any type definition in Delphi source). Even though should be enough to search for `TypeToFind =` without RegEx.

Comment: @TLama I worked this out by doing that search inside the Delphi IDE using Find in Files feature. I don't know the first thing about Indy, as I'm sure is quite obvious to regular visitors.